# How to record session at database table name?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to record my table name at session. Can I get help regarding the session?

```
    random r = new Random();

    int sayi = r.Next(0, 99999999);
    string sayi2 = sayi.ToString();
     //Create 
        using (MySqlConnection baglanti = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; user id=root; password=xxxx; database=de_db; pooling=false"))
        {

            baglanti.Open();

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE gecici"+ sayi2 +" (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(50))", baglanti);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            baglanti.Close();

        }
```

Comment: This question is not clear in this form

Comment: Not exactly related, but don't use the `Random` class as a unique session, try something like a GUID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting session variable is a simple as

```
Session["TableName"] = "gecici" + sayi2;
```

to retrieve, then

```
string tablename = Session["TableName"].toString();
```

Is this what you are looking for, where the name will be something like **gecici1234**?

Comment: hi steve my table name  gecici"+ sayi2 +" but i don't understand how can i add + sayi2 + ?  My table name be gecici12345678 after generate random number.

Comment: see my change to include the `gecici` prefix

Comment: Your welcome. Glad I could be of service.